# Implementation provided for BatchConfigurer is not connsidered when using @EnableBatchProcessing(modular=true)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am developing a sample application that Spring Batch with Spring Boot. My requirement is:

- Have my own implementation of `BasicBatchConfigurer` so that I can configure AsyncTaskExecutor and my own dataSource as I am using SAP HANA as DB for which databaseType is not supported.
- I want to use `@EnableBatchProcessing(modular=true)` so that I can register multiple jobs and launch them with separate Child Context

I have added all the required configurations. Without setting modular=true the Job is Launched and works as expected. It initializes the beans defined from my implementation of BasicBatchConfigurer.

However, once modular=true is set, the beans from my implementation are not initialized.

The code is hosted here: https://github.com/VKJEY/spring-framework-evaluation

I debugged further into the issue:

- Looks like, When we set modular=true, `BatchConfigurationSelector` uses ModularBatchConfiguration
- In ModularBatchConfiguration, there's a field  `Collection<BatchConfigurer> configurers`. This has been annotated as `@autowired`.
- I assume that this field is auto initialized if I provided a implementation
  of `BatchConfigurer` as it has been mentioned in the comments of `ModularBatchConfiguration` class as well
- However, While debugging I realized that the above field is still null beacuse of which, It loads `DefaultBatchConfigurer` and follows the default flow.

My question is why is that field `configurers` not being initialized in `ModularBatchConfiguration`? Am I missing something?

I am using Spring boot 2.1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is why is that field configurers not being initialized in ModularBatchConfiguration? Am I missing something?

You are hitting a lifecycle issue between Spring Boot custom auto-configuration that you defined in the `META-INF/spring.factories` file and Spring Batch configuration.

I debugged your code and here is how to fix the issue:

1. remove `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
   com.example.job.data.persistence.config.AsyncBatchConfigurer`
   from `META-INF/spring.factories` file. This is not needed as Spring Batch
   will detect the `AsyncBatchConfigurer` when it is declared as a bean.
   You can even remove this `spring.factories` file
2. remove `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(BatchConfigurer.class)` from `AsyncBatchConfigurer`:
   Since you declared this class as a `@Configuration` class, it will also be defined as a bean of type `BatchConfigurer` and will be detected by `ModularBatchConfiguration`

With these two changes, the field `configurers` in `ModularBatchConfiguration` is correctly autowired with your `AsyncBatchConfigurer`.

As a side note, you don't need the `AsyncBatchConfigurer#configurers` method as Spring will do the work of injecting all `BatchConfigurer` beans in `ModularBatchConfiguration`.

Hope this helps.